# Div % width does not seem accurate

Tags: css

I have some child divs (5 of them) set to a width of `20%`.

They have no padding/margin or border yet they still wrap to a new line in the parent div. Here is an example:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div id="child">Test</div>
    <div id="child">Test</div>
    <div id="child">Test</div>
    <div id="child">Test</div>
    <div id="child">Test</div>
</div>
```

The output shows:

```
Test       Test       Test       Test
Test
```

My `CSS`:

```
* { 
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box
 }

#parent{

width:500px;
color:white;
background-color:black;    

}

#child{
    width:20%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Shouldn't `width:20%;` work with 5 child divs, why do they wrap to a new line??

Here is  fiddle of it in action: **http://jsfiddle.net/aeG9q/2/**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The culprit is `display:inline-block`. Because of it, your divs start acting like real inline content, just like text and links. Because of this, the whitespace between the divs (they're all on  a new line in the source), is actually rendered, and in a normal font takes up a handful of pixels, thus pushing the total width of the 5 divs over the size of the parent.

To solve, either apply `font-size:0` to the parent (which causes some other problems) or use floating instead of `display:inline-block`.

Comment: Intersting, hmm im not a fan of floats they are such a pain to behave for me ! But thanks for the explaination, i have always wondered :)

Comment: you can as well put an html comment in between, so the gap doesn't exist anymore : </div><!-- no matter how much space or line break here , white-space is not anymore--><div>

Answer (score 3):

You can also remove the whitespace like in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aeG9q/3/)

```
<div id="parent"><!--
    --><div class="child">Test</div><!--
    --><div class="child">Test</div><!--
    --><div class="child">Test</div><!--
    --><div class="child">Test</div><!--
    --><div class="child">Test</div>
</div>
```